# Issue printing elements of the arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, element

i'm new to programming and stack overflow, so pardon my gibberish .Please i am having issues printing out the last three arrays. it prints out just the last element in the array.But when i use the console.log it prints all the elements out.I hope i am making sense. Kindly help. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">
    </head>


    <body>
      <h1>Score Sheet</h1>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      var candidateName = [];
      var candidates = 0;
      var moreCandidates = "y";

      while (moreCandidates == "y"){
        candidateName.push(prompt("Enter candidate name"));
        var noOfSubjects = prompt("How many subjects are you offering?");

        for(i = 1; i <= noOfSubjects; i++){
          var subName = [];
          var scores = [];
          var unit = [];
          subName.push(prompt("What is the subject name?"));
          console.log(subName);
          scores.push(prompt("Enter your subject score"));
          console.log(scores);
          unit.push(prompt("Enter your subject unit"));
          console.log(unit);
        }

        moreCandidates = prompt("Do you want to add more candidates? y/n");
        candidates++
     }

     document.write("Number of candidates is" + " " + candidates);
     document.write("<br/>");
     document.write(candidateName);
     document.write("<br/>");
     document.write(noOfSubjects);
     document.write("<br/>");
     document.write(subName);
     document.write("<br/>");
     // document.write(scores);
     // document.write("<br/>");
     // document.write(unit);

   </script>
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by `it prints out just the last element in the array.`. What is it?

Comment: for example if I input 3 subNames, 3scores, and 3 units it prints out the last elements i input. It ignores the first 2

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are resetting the arrays for each loop iteration so they will only ever contain one value. Declare them outside the loop instead.

Don't forget `var` for `i` otherwise it will be defined on the global scope and I would say consider a proper interface rather than using `prompt()` to get the values you are after it will provide a better user experience.

```
var subName = [];
var scores = [];
var unit = [];

for(var i = 1; i <= noOfSubjects; i++){
    subName.push(prompt("What is the subject name?")); 
    console.log(subName);
    scores.push(prompt("Enter your subject score"));
    console.log(scores);
    unit.push(prompt("Enter your subject unit"));
    console.log(unit);
}
```

If you want to use document write you could simply use [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) as in

`document.write(scores.join(", "))`

to print out the array values.

Comment: Okay, will try that. Thanks

Comment: I made the corrections but it's not quite right yet, can you try it out and see? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe (I haven't tested this) that you must use a loop to use `document.write` with an array:

```
for(var i = 0; i < candidateName.length; i++)
{
    document.write(candidateName[i]);
}
```

Have a look at these:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Comment: Thanks, but the candidateName[] should be able to take as many names as possible. the moreCandidate = y is supposed to stop the loop